# Xamarin Forms Picker raises two events

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have picker which is defined as:

```
<Picker
      Title="Identifier"
      ItemsSource="{Binding IdentifyUsing}"
      SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedId}"
/>
```

And in ViewModel, `SelectedId` is configured as below:

```
public string SelectedId
        {
            get => _selectedId; 
            set
            {
                SetProperty(ref _selectedId, GetAppropriateLabel(value)); <-- This code is executed twice 
                IsEnabled = true;
            }
        }
```

where `GetAppropriateLabel()` method is defined as below:

```
private string GetAppropriateLabel(string value)
{
    if (value.Contains("Member"))
       return "Member ID (ex: 999999999)";
    else if (value.Contains("Social"))
       return "Social Security Number (ex: 999-99-9999)";
    else if (value.Contains("StudentId"))
       return "Medicare Number (ex: ********-**)";
    else
       return value;
}
```

Now, if I pass the value which is part of `if-else` chain, `setter` of `SelectedId` is executed twice. And second time, the value comes as null and breaks the app. If the value which is not part of `if-else` chain is passed, then it is works correctly.

I have no idea why setter of `SelectedId` is executed twice for the values which are not part of `is-else` chain.

Is this related to two way binding or picker related issues? Did I understand binding incorrectly? Any idea what is going wrong?

Comment: I don't really follow why you're using the Picker this way.  The `SelectedItem` is supposed to be one of the values from `ItemsSource`.

Comment: null is often seen when binding to xaml. For a picker, it might be when the picker is closing. Either in the setter or in the method, test for null, and decide how to handle. Looks like you could return empty string instead. Then test app, see if that is actually visible to user. (If it happens while picker is closing, it won't be.)

Comment: @Jason, can you expand more on that please. According to MS docs(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/picker/populating-itemssource#responding-to-item-selection-1), ```SelectedItem``` can be used like that.

Comment: I don't see anything in the docs that has logic like yours in the `SelectedItem` setter